# subprocess.Popen line in flask app not running on pythonanywhere while it work on local machine.. any idea why or how to catch error?

Tags: flask, subprocess, popen, pythonanywhere

subprocess.Popen line (40) in flask app not running on pythonanywhere while it works on local machine.. tried different variation of the subprocess line but no luck. no error shown in error logs in pythonanywhere.
any idea why there is a difference to functionality on pythonanywhere vs local machine and how to fix or how to catch error of subprocess?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOgLH.png)

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request 
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread
import time 
import subprocess



app = Flask(__name__)


# config db
db = yaml.full_load(open('db.yaml')) 
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'xxx'
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "xxx"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = "xxx"
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "xxx"

mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
  if request.method =="POST":
    #fetch form data 
    userDetails=request.form
    title=userDetails["title"]
    location=userDetails["location"]
    radius=userDetails["radius"]
    email=userDetails["email"]
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO requests(title, location, radius, email) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (title, location, radius, email))
    mysql.connection.commit()
    cur.close()
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'file.py'])
    return render_template('donenew.html')
  return render_template("indexnew.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you checked error log for your web app on PA?  Also, try using absolute path for the `file.py`.

Comment: hi @caseneuve yes also used the absolute path, same outcome, no subprocess execution.  Error log doesnt show anything on PA, probably beause its a subprocess i assume. But there must be a way to show subprocess errors in the log file but didnt find a way yet.

Comment: That's strange -- I just tested this on my web app in PA and got the error I expected in the error log.

Comment: @caseneuve if i enter a wrong path to the file then i get the error but if everything is correct (-> i get output on local machine) it shows nothing anymore. on local machine works fine. not sure what the difference to PA could be.